# hide it with custom CSS in woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, customization

I have the following class in woocommerce and I want to hide it with custom CSS. How should I put?

```
<li class="product_cats_checklist_item checklist_item_859" data-item="859">
```

Answer (score 0):

Either this:

```
.product_cats_checklist_item.checklist_item_859 {
    display: none;
}
```

or this (the data attribute):

```
[data-item="859"]  {
     display:none;
}
```

Be aware the above will break if the product item attribute ever changes. Might be better to deactivate the product from the WooCommerce Product Manager.